# How to understand this

Tags: game-development

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29861691/22499336)

I am struggling to understand what the `crossHeight` and `crossWidth` are.

```js
function collide(r1,r2){
    var dx=(r1.x+r1.w/2)-(r2.x+r2.w/2);
    var dy=(r1.y+r1.h/2)-(r2.y+r2.h/2);
    var width=(r1.w+r2.w)/2;
    var height=(r1.h+r2.h)/2;
    var crossWidth=width*dy;
    var crossHeight=height*dx;
    var collision='none';
    //
    if(Math.abs(dx)<=width && Math.abs(dy)<=height){
        if(crossWidth>crossHeight){
            collision=(crossWidth>(-crossHeight))?'bottom':'left';
        }else{
            collision=(crossWidth>-(crossHeight))?'right':'top';
        }
    }
    return(collision);
}
```

Why is the `crossWidth` has `width * dy` my bad common sense would assume it should be `width * dx` because both width and x are related.

Comment: Post the (relevant) code you have doubts about. The current code, as you said yourself, is a simple rectable bounds check. But `crossHeight` and `crossWidth` are nowhere mentioned.

Comment: @Alejandro I done it